# how to find and visualize a spike/burst with kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

**what I have:**

24h logged data in elasticsearch with a number field containing the byte size of transmitted messages (microsecond granularity).
Via a date histogram I can easily drill down to ms-intervals to determine network traffic spikes.

[image: zoomed range in one second interval]

**what I need:**

a deterministic way to find the maximum traffic spike within the 24 hours based on a fixed size 100 ms interval.

```
find( max( sum(bytessize) of X ms interval)) over Yh range)
```

I'm new to the ELK-Stack, so any help how and where (elasticsearch or kibana) to solve such a problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, then something very similar to what you want can be done, and you are very close.

Click on the 'pencil' icon in the top right corder of you graph to edit the visualization. In your 'Y-Axis' aggregation choose 'Max' as the aggregation type.
In the 'X-Axis' aggregation section, I see you're already using a 'Date Histogram', so just define the interval to be 'Second' (That's the lowest possible interval in kibana, currently available)

Comment: my date historgram (as shown in the image) uses as y-axis sum(bytesize). I need to find the max(sum(bytesize)) applied to all intervals.

Comment: oh, i see. Then i don't think you'll be able to get that exact value from kibana